# How to publish two seperate Azure web sites from One VS Solution

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a solution with a Web API and a Web Site. I want to publish them to two different windows azure sites and setup the CI using CloudTFS. How can i do it? When i setup the CI, it always takes the start-up project to publish from Azure CI.

Thanks

Niranjan

Answer (score 0):

There's some extra steps that need to be taken to get both web sites into a single project, and I'm not 100% confident that CloudTFS will do it. Essentially, you'll need to build the second site, copy it entire root path into the first site, then build/package the first site. Finally, you'll need some extra config steps to help set IIS up for both sites.

You can find a couple example walkthroughs at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx
http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/
http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/

I'd likely start with Michael Collier's as its the most recent one and reflects a more current version of the Azure SDK.